# Using Ctrl or Alt AND backspace to delete last word in Bash

Tags: bash, linux-terminal

In Linux I'm used to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the last word but I don't know how to do it in Bash terminal.

In OS X I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to do the same thing.

Is there any way of making Bash recognize the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>- or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> key combination to delete last word?

In Linux I use `terminator` as terminal emulator, in OSX I use `iTerm2`.

Comment: Alt-⌫ a.k.a. Alt-← a.k.a. Alt-Backspace works perfectly fine for me.  I'm using Terminator 0.93.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>. It deletes the word before the cursor and works in every Bash.

See here for a list of [Bash keyboard shortcuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Keyboard_shortcuts).

Comment: Wow this may have changed how I use the terminal forever. Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: I am using the combination through ssh with `tcsh`, it clears everything before the cursor, not just one word before cursor.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to set *Option as Meta key* in iTerm's preferences (*Profiles » Keys*).

`backward-kill-word` is bound to `Meta-Rubout` (i.e. Opt-Backspace) by default.

The same option exists (albeit less flexible) in Apple's Terminal.app.

Comment: Actually, you have to use the "+Esc" setting. Only setting it to "acts as: Meta" results in `?` being printed instead of the word getting deleted.

Comment: @slhck Not for me. But since the developers recommend it anyway, it can't be a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a file `.inputrc` in your home directory and add this content inside:

```
"\C-h": backward-kill-word
```

Comment: Note that this and `C-w` in the accepted answer differ by what is considered a "word". `C-w` will delete from the cursor position until it encounters non-space characters and then a space (i.e., `"this is a/se=weird   |test"` where `|` marks the cursor position will yield `"this is test"`). In contrast, the `C-h` bind here (which can be bound using `bind '"\C-h": backward-kill-word"` in a `.bashrc`) would yield `"this is a/se= test"`, as it basically delimits words on what a bash variable would, not just spaces.

Answer (score 2):

In terminator you can use the following "[plugin](https://bitbucket.org/ede/dotfiles/src/39f8449529ed83f7acf472da03f6795a719dacfa/.config/terminator/plugins/killword.py?at=default)", along with

```
[keybindings]
    kill_word = <Control>BackSpace
```

in your config file. This will map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd>→<kbd>DEL</kbd>, another shorcut to delete last word.

Comment: Unfortunately this stopped working in terminator 1.9. Could you provide a fix by any chance?

Comment: Sorry, stopped using terminator long time ago...

Answer (score 2):

As some have mentioned, this may also depend on your terminal emulator.  For example in KDE's **Konsole**, you can define the behavior of Ctrl+Backspace in the key bindings settings of the profile:

Set `Backspace+Ctrl` to the output `\E\x7f` (default `\b`)

[image: Konsole Key Binding List]

Answer (score 0):

You can just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd> instead of the normal <kbd>Strg</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd>.